# Get value of nested maps in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, nested

I have a map with the following structure:

```
Map[String, Map[String, String]]
```

Is there an elegant way of getting the value of the inner map?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just do it the normal way... twice.

```
val m = Map("a" -> Map("b" -> "c"))
m("a")("b")  // c
```

The first operation `m("a")` returns the inner `Map[String,String]`.  The second operation `that("b")` returns the String inside of that returned Map.

It's the same as:

```
val m = Map("a" -> Map("b" -> "c"))
val m2 = m("a")  // Map(b -> c)
m2("b")          // c
```

On the other hand, if you think that they keys may not be there, then do this:

```
for {
  x <- m.get("a")   // x = Map(b -> c)
  y <- x.get("b")   // y = c
} yield y
// Some(c)

for {
  x <- m.get("a")   // x = Map(b -> c)
  y <- x.get("d")   // fails
} yield y
// None

for {
  x <- m.get("c")   // fails
  y <- x.get("d")   // doesn't run
} yield y
// None
```

For your example, `key2` is an `Option`, just like `m.get(key1)`, so you can handle it the same way:

```
val key1: String = "a"
val key2: Option[String] = Some("b")
for { 
  value1 <- m.get(key1)
  k2 <- key2
  value2 <- value1.get(k2) 
} yield value2
// Some(c)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the "for" section, suppose I need to get the value of the second map ("b" is used in the example) from a var that is defined as Option[String]. Is there a neat way of doing it?

Comment: Some(1).flatMap(Map(1 -> 2).get) - where Some(1) is your lookup key

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it... Here is my code:
def getValue(key1: String, key2: Option[String]): Option[String] = {
    for {
      value1 <- myMap.get(key1)
      value2 <- value1.get(key2) 
    } yield

Of course, this part will not work: value1.get(key2), since key2 is an option.

Comment: I had to use `DerivedFeaturesLocations("outer_key").asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]("inner_key")`. Why is that?