# How to get value from nested map of type AnyRef

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

So I have a map of type

```
Map[String, AnyRef]
```

When I print this map through `println`, it gives the following output

```
Map(revision -> 
 Map(comment -> "string1", 
     contributor -> Map(id -> "int1", username -> "string2"), 
     format -> "string3", 
     id -> "int2", 
     minor -> None, 
     model -> "string4", 
     parentid -> "int3", 
     sha1 -> "string5", 
     text -> Map(_VALUE -> "VALUE-THAT-I-WANT-TO-GET", 
     space -> ""), 
     timestamp -> Timestamp, 
     title -> "string6"))
```

Now as you see in the map, I want to get the value against key `_VALUE`.
I tried getting it the way you get from a nested map explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28998429/10190191) answer, but it didn't work may be because it's of type `AnyRef` 
What is the best way to get it in a simple string variable?

> I am sorry if map is not readable enough, I will accept if you edit it in a better way. But it had be posted complete to clear sense of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let's say you have a coworker that produces code like that. Of course that person gets fired for being incompetent. Alas, you get stuck with the task of working with it until it can be rewritten into proper Scala.

Here's one thing you might do. It compiles with a warning but appears to produce the desired result.

```
def extract(m :collection.Map[String,AnyRef], key :String) :Option[String] = {
  if (m.isDefinedAt(key)) Some(m(key).toString)
  else {
    val res = m.values
               .collect{case ma:Map[String,AnyRef] => extract(ma,key)}
               .dropWhile(_.isEmpty)
    if (res.isEmpty) None else res.head
  }
}

extract(badMap, "_VALUE") //res0: Option[String] = Some(VALUE-THAT-I-WANT-TO-GET)
extract(badMap, "_XALUE") //res1: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, when I try to call this function it produces error `type mismatch=> found: scala.collection.Map[String,AnyRef] || required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, _]`

Comment: @saadi; Code has been adjusted.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. You should also check @jgoday's answer, it works without a warning but is less generic I guess.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your map (alias anymap) to define a getAs[T] method that returns an Option an so on ...

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

val m: Map[String, AnyRef] = Map("a" -> Map("b" -> Map("c" -> "d")))

type AnyMap = Map[String, AnyRef]

implicit class AnyMapWrapper(m: AnyMap) {
    def getAs[T](key: String)(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]): Option[T] = m(key) match {
        case i: T => Some(i.asInstanceOf[T])
      case _ => None
  }
}

println {
    m.getAs[AnyMap]("a").flatMap(_.getAs[AnyMap]("b")).map(_("c"))
}

println {
  for {
    a <- m.getAs[AnyMap]("a")
    b <- a.getAs[AnyMap]("b")
  } yield b("c")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I try to do `val m: Map[String, AnyRef] = myMap`, it says `Expression of type scala.collection.Map[scala.Predef.String, AnyRef] does not conform to type  scala.Predef.Map[scala.Predef.String, AnyRef]`. What can I do now?

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jgoday/J6e4R1h9SEeSWFn6rRytAA maybe you want to import scala.collection.Map ( i think predef Map is scala.collection.immutable.Map )

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks, but I am going to have to accept @jwvh's answer as it is more generic, readable & understandable for my inexperienced self. Your works without any warning tho.

Answer (score 0):

The verbose (but explicit) version could be:

```scala
yourMap.get("revision") collect {
  case Some(otherMap: Map[String, AnyRef]) => otherMap.get("text")
} collect {
  case Some(yetAnotherMap: Map[String, AnyRef]) => yetAnotherMap.get("_VALUE")
}
```